# Execution failed Twilio SMS (Java)

Tags: java, gradle, twilio

I am trying to send SMS messages with Twilio. I have followed all the instructions and have JAVA_HOME environmental variable set up. When I run the program I get:

Execution failed for task ':StockAlertClass:SMS.main()'.

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':StockAlertClass:SMS.main()'. <36 internal calls>
  Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1<98 internal calls>

My java class is:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class SMS {
    // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("HiddenForPrivacy");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("HiddenForPrivacy");

    public static void Message() {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("+HiddenForPrivacy"),
                new PhoneNumber("HiddenForPrivacy"),
                "Test ").create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message();
    }
}
```

build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
if (hasProperty('buildScan')) {
    buildScan {
        termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
        termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.+'
    compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.+'
    implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "8.21.0"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio
    runtimeOnly group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '8.21.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am concerned with how you shared these lines:

```java
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("HiddenForPrivacy");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("HiddenForPrivacy");
```

You should not have to hide the key in these lines. Instead, you should set your Account SID and Auth Token as environment variables called `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN` and then your code should look like:

```java
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = System.getenv("ACCOUNT_SID");
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = System.getenv("AUTH_TOKEN");
```

If you have instead used the actual Account Sid and Auth Token in those calls, then my guess is that your code fails because they aren't set properly.

I recommend reading this blog post on [working with environment variables in Java](https://www.twilio.com/blog/working-with-environment-variables-in-java) for more detail.